# application.exe.config file issue when installing on a clean machine

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I have created an installer project in WPF. when I run the application on my computer, it works fine. I set a minimum requirement for the .net framework 4.5. But if I run the application on another machine (with newly installed windows 7), the application crashes.

Below is event viewer log:

> ```
> Installer exception
> Faulting application name: MyInstaller.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x55572605
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7bafa
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
> Fault offset: 0x0000b727
> Faulting process id: 0x398
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d08fca117f3e62
> Faulting application path: C:\Users\self\Downloads\MyInstaller.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
> Report Id: 517dc0dd-fbbd-11e4-a332-b083fe4d72a6
>
> Application: MyInstaller.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> Stack:
>    at MyInstaller.App.Main(System.String[])
> ```

I tried to create "Window event log" inside `Main()` try-catch method, but the application was not able to reach to that point.

When I send myinstaller.config.exe file with project exe file in the new installed machine, then it shows error. That the application does not meet requirement.

In my machine myinstaller.config.exe  is not requirement, even after I uninstall framework 4.5 and 4.0.

Comment: Sorry for sounding condescending but are you sure you have Dotnet4.5 on the target machine?

Comment: On current machine, i have framework 4.5. But on testing machine framework 4.5 doesn't exist. i am expecting error message in place of application crash.